# How to update strange characters in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, character-encoding, cpanel

I am facing this problem with my database server. First, I bought a server from Godaddy they have database server following:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 5.6.51-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: cp1252 West European (latin1)
```

So when I enter Chinese characters from my website it appears like this in the database

```
 ç¾Žå˜‰11c10
```

But it shows right when I retrieve those data from the database and show them on the website again. Like this:

```
 你好世界
```

Now, My problem is, I have changed my hosting server. I am on the Bluehost server now. They have different database server like this:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: Percona Server
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 5.7.23-23 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 23, Revision 500fcf5
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

It doesn't work like Godaddy's server.

I can't change my database server charset from PHPMyAdmin on Bluehost. I am open up to any solutions. It will be better if I update the strange characters and make them Chinese characters again.

Comment: It's a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python): `print('你好世界'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252'))` returns `ä½ å¥½ä¸–ç•Œ`. Please  [edit] your question to enhance your [mcve]. Maybe Client charset, Connection charset, etc ( Database, Table, Field, … )

Answer (score 0):

You must use `utf8mb4` -- both for the columns that might contain Chinese characters and for the connection (assuming the client is using UTF-8).

Latin1 will not work.  cp1252 will not work.  MySQL's "utf8" does not contain all Chinese characters; utf8mb4 is needed instead.

More discussion:  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

If you provide a sample of `SELECT HEX(col) ...` and the Chines that you are expecting, I can probably provide a "fix" for the data.  For example:

```
CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT('å¥½ä¸–ç•Œ' USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4) --> '好世界'
```

I would feel safer trying to "fix" the text in SQL than in the client (eg Python).